# Header not showing in Magento 1.9 site

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently administering a Magento 1.9 website which hasn't been used in a long time. The site owner recently started to use the site again, and we noticed that the header section of the site is now gone. When I first set the site up, the site logo, language selector etc would show on the site header, but now that header is entirely gone ...

Initially I thought this was an issue with the language selector, so I went into the admin panel and re-configured the languages, but no dice. I've looked under all the options in the configuration section as well, but for the life of me cannot figure out why the header of the site has suddenly disappeared.

If anyone could point me to the right area in the Magento admin to take a look at this, or even how to debug etc, it would be much appreciated. The rest of the site works just fine - it is just the header (with the site logo, language switcher, login links etc) that is not showing up.

The login links are still there at the BOTTOM of the homepage - and seem to work, so I'm not sure why the header itself is not showing.

Here is what I see in terms of "inspecting the homepage" - -

```
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #youama-email: (More info:) <input type=​"text" placeholder=​"E-mail address" id=​"youama-email" name=​"youama-email" value>​ <input type=​"text" placeholder=​"E-mail address" id=​"youama-email" name=​"youama-email" value>​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #youama-password: (More info) <input type=​"password" placeholder=​"Password" id=​"youama-password" name=​"youama-password" value>​ <input type=​"password" placeholder=​"Password" id=​"youama-password" name=​"youama-password" value>​
2gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/0TSSoT4c2BI?v=2&alt=jsonc:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/0TSSoT4c2BI?v=2&alt=jsonc' from origin 'http://blantotrading.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
2www-widgetapi.js:100 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://blantotrading.com').
```

What is more vexing is that the code seems to be all there when I look at the source code ...

Thanks!

Comment: is there any log error ?

Comment: Nope. No error logs whatsoever. The only thing I saw was what I've provided above (this when I was using Google Chrome's inspect feature). Indeed baffling - any tips would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: No, there is no error log. That is what makes it all the more strange....

Comment: by "the code is all there" do you mean in the browser "view source" or the theme files on disk?

Comment: I mean it's all there when I "view source" in Chrome. Can't see why it wouldn't be there in the theme files as well though ...